# Disable "azure-jobs-host-output" / "azure-webjobs-hosts/output-logs" messages

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

My goal is not to clutter blobs.

• I am using latest webjobs sdk at the time of writing (ver 1.1.1). Using Queues, running WebJobs, creating files, deleting files and writing database entries.

• I tried searching but it seems that "azure-jobs-host-output" and "azure-webjobs-hosts/output-logs" are automatically created and filled with lots of stuff.

• My effort so far after searching through web is just this one line of code I have written in order to stop some logging:

```
config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Error;
```

This is supposed to restrict logs to error level. Which is good I understand but I am not sure *which one* of the above will it restrict.

• Can I disable the *other* one completely?

• Or more precisely, can I stop/disable **all** logging/logs and bring it to bare minimum, to only the ones which are absolutely necessary to run webjobs sdk?

Thanks for reading, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel` only controls output written to the Console. It sounds like you want to turn off Dashboard logging (if you don't want to use the WebJobs Dashboard). Those additional blob containers that you mentioned are the storage for all the Dashboard analytics logs. To disable that, you can set `config.DashboardConnectionString` to null. That will completely disable all Dashboard logging.

At that point, you'll be running with the bare minimum :)

Comment: Well I had already tried with App Settings and removed Dashboard settings connection string from there, but it threw an InvalidOperationException and message was telling me *how* to put it back again in different manners, with no mention of disabling.

Setting:

`config.DashboardConnectionString = null;` 

in code however did the trick. My testing showed now more clutter in Blobs. So perhaps App Settings error needs to go or edit your answer?
Anyway, its working now so cheers for that. :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Please log a bug in the public repo (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues) for this so we can improve.